# Undefined method 'dump' for psych:Module

Tags: ruby, minitest

When running minitest with Ruby v 2.2.0, I get the following error, does anyone have advice on how to remedy this?

Error :

```
/Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) i
n <class:Notifier>': undefined method `dump' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nenv-0.2.0/lib/nenv/environment/dumper.rb:5:in `call'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nenv-0.2.0/lib/nenv/environment/dumper.rb:5:in `dump'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nenv-0.2.0/lib/nenv/environment.rb:47:in `block in _create_env_method'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:93:in `add'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in detect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in `each'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in `detect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in `block in detect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:61:in `each'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:61:in `detect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:105:in `initialize'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in `new'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in `connect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/guard-2.12.7/lib/guard/notifier.rb:11:in `connect'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/guard-2.12.7/lib/guard/notifier.rb:31:in `notify'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.3.1/lib/guard/minitest/notifier.rb:34:in `noti
fy'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/guard-minitest-2.3.1/lib/guard/minitest/reporter.rb:11:in `repo
rt'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.7.0/lib/minitest.rb:638:in `each'
        from /Users/jamie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/minitest-5.7.0/lib/minitest.rb:638:in `report'
```

...........

Comment: please share full stack trace and gemfile. it looks like some sort of issue with the psych gem but it's hard to tell from just 1 line

Comment: Here's more of the stack track, no gemfile was used just minitest/autorun, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the same issue by using Ruby 2.3.0 instead of Ruby 2.2.0.